# Show pod names without id part

Tags: bash, kubectl

is there any possibility to cut off the id part of the pod name? I just need the application name.

Here is an example:

I get the list of pods with the command:
`kubectl get pod --all-namespaces -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name --field-selector status.phase=Running`

- blabla-admin-management-6779fdc6db-6zp5z
- event-default-stan-0
- kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-q574j
- aws-node-lzrse

But I need the following output:

- blabla-admin-management
- event-default-stan
- kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter
- aws-node

I wrote a bash script which identifies the parts with numbers in it to cut them off, but it does not work for all examples, see aws-node-lzrse.

Comment: Could you please share your script? I have the same problem as well.